# How to use PyInstaller on complex programs?

Tags: python, compilation, pyinstaller

I have a complex program which has total of 7-8 python files. They all are imported to one main file which runs them. It uses OpenCV, pytesseract and AHK. Both pytesseract and AHK needs extra installers to work. I have a ton of image files and I want one executable which I can share.

I get NoneType object has no attribute shape error, which is tied to OpenCV not able to read static files.

I tried:

```
pyinstaller myprogram.py
```

and:

```
pyinstaller --onefile myprogram.py
```

As I said I don't really know PyInstaller so I need help.

Answer (score 0):

You can write pyinstaller --onefile -w myprogram.py in cmd and then put all .py files and .exe in the same directory and run the executable
(-w) command is for not showing the cmd window

Comment: But I want the code to be one executable. And I don't want the code to be visible.

Comment: You can try this pyinstaller --onefile --add-data="*;.py" -w myprogram.py you can add all py files in myprogram.py but it can not work all the time

Comment: If the file is "static file", which is like config files, you could just use `--add-data` (with --one-file of course). Else, if the file was imported by other `.py` script, PyInstaller will automatically include that.

Comment: @gfdsweds AutoHotKey just gives error. I think I will pass on PyInstaller unluckily.